# Get collection of products of all stores

Tags: collection, product-list

It is possible to get in only one collection the list of products from all stores (with different translations of the products attributes)?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible you can simply get all those by going loops

Load all of the stores and then load categories on those stores -> and then load all of the products in those stores.

Let me know if you need further code as well?

Comment: Why do you need to get the categories?

Comment: Because you can not simply get all products by store id

Answer (score 1):

You can do it even easier:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: This collects all store views' data as well?

Comment: Unless you apply `addStoreFilter()`.

Comment: I don't see how this could work as OP intends - the collection item data will be fetched with `admin` store scope. Have you tested?

Comment: But each product in `admin` scope belongs to at least one store. Right?

Comment: I think OP wants each product attribute with all translations from one collection.

Comment: Oh, I missed translations thing.